# How to make swagger-maven-plugin write swagger.json into target/classes in addition to fat jar, so Eclipse can find it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger

Our SpringBoot app has a pom.xml that uses the swagger-maven-plugin, and when we run locally with "mvn spring-boot:run", we can view the swagger docs successfully.

However, if we run the app from Eclipse, using "Run As"->"Spring Boot", and then visit the swagger page, it says it can't find the swagger.json file.

I looked further and determined that the "fat jar" that we produce has the swagger.json file at `META-INF/resources/<servicename>/swagger/swagger.json`.  I tried simply extracting that file and placing it in `target/classes` and then running the app from Eclipse, and now I can see the swagger docs properly.

I'd like to make the build do this automatically.

I inspected the docs for the swagger plugin, and I didn't see anything about this, but I didn't really expect to.  Is there some other way to do this cleanly?